# Which kind of analysis could be made to associate a set of genes to clinical values?

Tags: regression, clustering, categorical-data, genetics

I have a set of 5 genes that can be mutated or not, so therefore are intended as dichotomous yes/no vars. I want to identify the effect of the mutation of this genes on a continuous response var.

The tests I thought about are these:

- Regression analysis using the genes as covariates to assess the independent effect of a single mutation.
- Regression analysis using an association var which describe every possible combination of status (pattern) for the five genes. This var has 21 levels.
- Regression analysis using simply the number of mutated genes, independently from which gene is mutated. Thus a ordinal factor with 5 levels.

Any other ideas?

Next I'd like to use some clustering technique to group mutation patterns in 3/4 groups related to the continuous response.

Plotting the average of my response var for every pattern, I can see that it's possible to identify groups of response.

[image]

Which technique can be used to cluster the pattern in group that maximize the difference in the response var?

UPDATE

I thought of a solution and I'd like to hear your opinion. I aggregated the response data into the different patterns by averaging (like you see in the picture above).
Then I used kmeans to divide the 21 patterns using the averaged response var. This way I obtained group 1 which contains patterns 1 to 3, group 3 contains patterns 20 and 21 and group 2 contains the rest.
This seems a good solution. What troubles me is that by averaging, I eliminated all information about variability and numerosity in every pattern. Any comments?

Comment: Are you sure that all mutations of the same gene have the same effect? For example, NOTCH mutations in cancers can be either activating or inactivating. In such a case, "mutated" isn't simply a yes/no variable.

Comment: Well to know this it's the purpose of the study! Most gene anyway have trivial effect taken alone, that's why I'm trying to see the join effect of the genes as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your last approach is to be avoided at all costs.  Because it involves double dipping, it will find patterns in any random data.  The approach of using rank correlation to see if there is an association between the number of mutations and Y is promising.  It assumes that all 5 mutations are priori equally impactful on Y.  The general way to test for association is to run a perfectly multiplicity-adjusted chunk test with 5 d.f. that simultaneously relates the 5 indicator variables to Y, e.g., a Kruskal-Wallis rank ANOVA.

The idea of fitting several models should really be avoided also, vs. pre-specifying a single model with 5 covariates.  Don't use an ad hoc procedure when a formal procedure has existed for almost a century.

Comment: Dear Prof. thanks for the answer! it's been 9 years now and I don't even remember what was that about. Today I'd just for a regression approach with three models, assuming the causal independence of one mutation over the other: 1. simple additive regression; 2. a saturated model with all interactions with strong null priors (horseshoe?) on the interaction terms; 3. put all combinations into a factor var to model as a random intercept to rank the outcome by mutation combination with shrinkage.

Comment: Worthwhile approaches.  I'm glad you are thinking of penalizing interaction terms.  It's likely that unless N is very large the optimum penalty is $\infty$ which means you'd have to assume additivity.